# Adding Image to 2d Game in Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to add a simple 2d Image (.png format) to my 2d Game. My game consists of a Game View Class that extends surface view, a GameState Class, that Controls the logic of the game, and draws the canvas and a Main Activity. My GameState class has this method:

```
// the draw method
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {

    // Clear the screen
    canvas.drawRGB(20, 20, 20);

    // set the colour
    paint.setARGB(200, 0, 200, 0);

    // // draw the bats
    // canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_bottomBatX, _bottomBatY, _bottomBatX
    // + _batLength, _bottomBatY + _batHeight), paint); // bottom bat

}
```

It is responsible for drawing all the objects on the game. I can easily draw a rectangle. But i cannot figure out how to draw an Image into my game. I plan on having the image move dynamically (like a sprite).

How can i draw a sprite inside of the above method?

I cannot do it this way:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

since GameState does not extend View

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be.

- first you need to store your image in the asset folder
- then you need to call the AssetManager to get the assets in your assets folder

  `Bitmap yourImage;
   AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();`
- get the byte stream of your image

  `InputStream inputStream;
   inputStream = assetManager.open("yourImage.png");
   // path is relative to the assets folder`
- let the BitmapFactory do its work in decoding it and storing it to the yourImage variable of type Bitmap

  `yourImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
   inputStream.close();`
- then you need to call a method in the canvas object

  `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, paint);`

  The parameters of the method are:
  bitmap The bitmap to be drawn
  x  The position of the left side of the bitmap being drawn
  y  The position of the top side of the bitmap being drawn
  paint  The paint used to draw the bitmap (usualy this is null)

Example:
    `canvas.drawBitmap(yourImage, 100, 100, null);`